# PHP: If header location fails, can we bypass?

Tags: php, redirect

I have an *URL schema* for mobile App like-

```
$appUrl = 'testapp://testpage/10';
```

Now from PHP, users need to be *redirected* inside the App- if the App is *installed*, without showing the page content. So, am doing this-

```
header('location: '.$appUrl);
```

But, if the App is not installed, want to bypass the redirection and show the entire page.

Am also sending a **Flag** to check before redirection. Like-

```
if($hasAppFlag)
{
    header('location: '.$appUrl);
    exit;
}
```

But the `$hasAppFlag`  is not going to be *right in all cases*. So want to bypass- if failed.

Currently am testing in Browser, and its giving blank screen, as the app is not installed.
Is there a way to do this in PHP? 
[can do that in JS/Jquery, if there is no way.]

**IMP:**

As, it will open the APP in client side, and the $hasAppFlag will come through SMS to phone number;
So, if the User switches to a New Phone without having the APP, then- there will be no App installed. and redirection to testapp://testpage/10 will FAIL.

**So  $hasAppFlag is not always be right**

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the bypass you talk about, just the opposite step to if($hasAppFlag)?  If so, can't you just add an 'else' statement

```
if($hasAppFlag) {
}
else {
bypass
}
```

Steve

Comment: not like that. As, it will open the APP in client side, and the $hasAppFlag will come through SMS to phone number; So, if the User switches to a New Phone without having the APP, then- there will be no App installed. and redirection to testapp://testpage/10 will FAIL

Comment: @AviC so you should try to detect in advance whether the user switched to a new phone, right? If there's no way for you to find out if this happened, then there's not much you can do to fix the code you posted. I'm sure there are ways to handle it, but the issue is not in itself in the code you posted in any case.

Comment: The answer I think, Avi, is to focus on making the boolean $hasAppFlag, always be correct i.e. alter the logic for setting the boolean flag - you might want to post another question on how to alter the logic if you're having issues here?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your code as it is: either `$hasAppFlag` is true and the `header` will execute and redirect, or the code located just after the closing bracket will run.

There is nothing to change in your code.

Comment: As explained in my answer there are only 2 options: either the condition in the `if` statement is true, then the `header` will run. Or the condition is false, then the code after the closing bracket will run.